# How to extract RGB value from COLORREF in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, rgb

Actually i am trying to extract RGB value from COLORREF but not getting Value in range of 0 to 255. Instead of that i am getting some string always. **eg:0000017153665268**
i used below method:

```
    COLORREF obj_Colorref = obj_CColorDialog.GetColor();
    RGBTRIPLE rgb;
    rgb.rgbtRed = GetRValue(obj_Colorref);
    rgb.rgbtGreen = GetGValue(obj_Colorref);
    rgb.rgbtBlue = GetBValue(obj_Colorref);

    CString sRed;
    CString sGreen;
    CString sBlue;
    sRed.Format(L"%d", rgb.rgbtRed);
    sGreen.Format(L"%d", rgb.rgbtGreen);
    sBlue.Format(L"%d", rgb.rgbtBlue);
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("..//Projects//Ribbon//x64//color.txt");
    file << "#"<<"\n"<<"#"<< sRed << ",";
    file << sGreen << ",";
    file << sBlue << ",";
```

please help me out.

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: it is VC++. I am using  visual studio 2015 and MFC (it is c++ object oriented library)

Comment: Visual Studio comes with one of the best debuggers you'll find. Why aren't you using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this:

```
file << "#"<<"\n"<<"#"<< sRed << ",";
file << sGreen << ",";
file << sBlue << ",";
```

It prints `wchar_t` based `CString` to `char`-based stream.

`wchar_t*` does not print as string into `basic_ostream<char>`.

Easiest way to fix is probably to avoid `CString` altogether:

```
file << std::to_string((int)rgb.rgbtBlue) << ",";
```

Or maybe even:

```
file << (int)rgb.rgbtBlue << ",";
```